# Pandas DataFrame rolling count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counting

I have the following pandas dataframe (just an example):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','b','c','a']), columns = ['Data'])
```

```
   Data
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     b
4     b
5     c
6     c
7     c
8     c
9     b
10    c
11    a
```

The goal is to get another column, *Stats*, that count the element of *Data* column as following:

```
   Data Stats
0     a      
1     a      
2     a    a3
3     b      
4     b    b2
5     c      
6     c      
7     c      
8     c    c4
9     b    b1
10    c    c1
11    a    a1
```

Where, for example, *a3* means "three consecutive *a* elements", *c4* means "four consecutive *c* elements" and so on...

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `groupby`:

```
counts = df.groupby((df['Data'] != df['Data'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1

df['Stats'] = np.where(df['Data'] != df['Data'].shift(-1),
                       df['Data'] + counts.astype(str), '')

print(df)

   Data Stats
0     a      
1     a      
2     a    a3
3     b      
4     b    b2
5     c      
6     c      
7     c      
8     c    c4
9     b    b1
10    c    c1
11    a    a1
```

Comment: thank you @jpp I will study both solutions, yours and the one from jezrael.

Answer (score 1):

Create helper `Series` `s` for consecutive values of column `Data`, get count per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and last repalce duplicated values to empty `string`s:

```
s = df['Data'].ne(df['Data'].shift()).cumsum()
a = df.groupby(s)['Data'].transform('size')

df['Stats'] = np.where(~s.duplicated(keep='last'), df['Data'] + a.astype(str), '')
print (df)
   Data Stats
0     a      
1     a      
2     a    a3
3     b      
4     b    b2
5     c      
6     c      
7     c      
8     c    c4
9     b    b1
10    c    c1
11    a    a1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     4
10    5
11    6
Name: Data, dtype: int32

print (a)
0     3
1     3
2     3
3     2
4     2
5     4
6     4
7     4
8     4
9     1
10    1
11    1
Name: Data, dtype: int64
```

Without removing duplicates solution is simplier:

```
df['Stats'] = df['Data'] + a.astype(str)
print (df)

   Data Stats
0     a    a3
1     a    a3
2     a    a3
3     b    b2
4     b    b2
5     c    c4
6     c    c4
7     c    c4
8     c    c4
9     b    b1
10    c    c1
11    a    a1
```

Comment: thank you @jezrael for the solution, I will study it for improve my knowledge on python

Comment: @Gilberto - I only pointed it because I see my solution was accepted and then no ;)

Comment: I wanted to give both the check. To me both solutions solve the problem and I think they're both very interesting to me (I'm quite new to python)